# wifi signal strength icon, how to change it?

Tags: wireless, icons

I use ubuntu all days.
I always look at the wifi icon to see if it is working and how well (like all of us I guess).
And it looks like this here: [image]

But...
For a long time, I've been feeling confused when I use my smartphone and what the icons there mean (mostly when making choices on it's firewall). On smartphone, the wifi is like [image], as we all know too.

So, the wifi on ubuntu, shows the same icon that represents the mobile connection on smartphones!!

I just wanted (by showing the obvious) to demonstrate the problem I am having without doubts.

If it is related to the theme I am using, I do not want to change the whole theme, it would just make it complicated to get used to new icons.

So, I need to know where are such signal strenth wifi icons so I can specifically customize them. Even if I have to recompile something :/

Ubuntu 16.04

**Partial/temporary solution**

It was the oxygen theme that I enabled long ago (since 14.04 upgraded to 16.04) using a "gnome 3 tweak tool".

To fix, I went to configurations for "Appearance" and simply changing from "ambiance (default)" to "radiance" and back to "ambiance (default)" fixed it.

It fixed the main icon on the tray, and also all icons on the dropdown list for connections.

**Partial/temporary solution's Limitation**

But I am quite lost now, all icons changed.. I got used to the oxygen icon theme, and it is quite cool, now I am trying to find how to re-enable the oxygen theme and just change the wifi singal strength icons.

So, the the main question/request still persists.

Comment: Standard Ubuntu use the exact same icon you're used to in the smartphone. So, yes, it has to do either with the theme or the (non-Unity) desktop environment you're using.

Comment: I updated the question, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy all these files (from the theme where I think they are ok)
`/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/24/nm-signal-*.svg`
to a newly created user folder:
`~/.icons/oxygen/24x24/status/`
(copy the 24x24 folder to a 16x16 folder with the same unchanged files and it will work also for the dropdown menu)

As I understand, they work as a simple override as soon I chose the oxygen theme using the tweaker.

Without this override, they fall back to
`/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/nm-signal-*.png`
that looks like a cellphone signal strength.